# Pine Script "strategy.position_size" is delayed by a candle

Tags: pine-script

The function --strategy.position_size-- is not updated to the order.
In this code I will have the position_size +1/-1, but change the candle after my order.
Offset=1 to view the position value.
Is there a way to keep the position updated?

```
//@version=4
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)

length = input( 3 )
overSold = input( 40 )
overBought = input( 60 )
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, length)
co = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co)
        strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    if (cu)
        strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
        
        
plot(strategy.position_size, title="position", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr, offset=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be the argument you're using in the strategy() function. Perhaps your strategy would give you the desired output if you set process_orders_on_close to false. I would then remove the offset from the plot of position size, else set it to 0.

Another consideration is that the price variable is fetching price at candle close and calculating the entry and exit based on closing price which is being fed into the rsi function. As such, the strategy script would only detect entry and exit condition within the price action of a historical candle at the candle close. As this is the candle which triggered the trade signal, it's the candle marked on the chart as an entry or exit. The order is actually placed at candle close and the position size is then changed to reflect the new position in the new opening candle, which you might be interpreting as a delay of one bar, which it really isn't.

Real-time candles with strategies that place orders based on current price of live data are treated differently, however, and require other considerations.

If you just want to move the position size plot back one candle, then the plot strategy argument would be offset = -1, but I believe the plot for the current candle would be NA until the close of the candle.

Comment: After many tests I still haven't found the solution, perhaps it is not possible.